# Passing a parameter to a php file stored in a variable via batch

Tags: php, windows-7, batch-file, parameter-passing

I want to call a php file I have from a batch file on windows 7, and it takes a parameter.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
php myfile.php %1
```

Where `%1` is a value passed to the batch file.

When the php file executes though it does not replace `%1` with the value of that variable.

How can I get it so that I can do this?

Comment: How do you try to access the variable in php?

Comment: I use `$argv`. The thing is though if I command out `@echo off` in the batch file, it seems to be passing `%1` literally rather than substituting in it's actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
php myfile.php %~1
```

or:

```
php myfile.php "%~1"
```

Comment: You should add explanations about what you do different and why

Comment: @HugoDozois The difference is the `~` symbol.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I get that, though the answer would be improved if the poster explained WHY he put that. It's just an advice to provide better and clearer answers. Because the post ended up in LQ review queue.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can check the arguments passed to a script using [$argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), the value of your variable must be in `$argv[1]`, because `$argv[0]` is the name of the script. Also, you can check the number of params using [$argc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php)